# ImportHTML Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

> `=ImportHtml("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/ranbaxylabs/consolidated-profit-loss/RL","table",5)`

The above formula presents me with a nice table (profit and loss st) for ranbaxylabs for the years Dec 12 to Dec 08, however if you goto the link within you will notice that the table has a link as "Previous year" which gives same information for Dec 07 to Dec 04, where the url link is same.

Is there any way I can get this table "Dec 07 to Dec 04" in GSheet, by ImportHTML or some GAS script?

Comment: Can you explain more your needs, I didn't got it.

Comment: Thanks br araujo, if you go to the link within formula, you can see a P&L statement from Dec 12 to Dec 08 & a previous year link, we capture this P&L info in Gsheet with importhtml, now if you click the previous year link, it will show P&L for Dec 07 to Dec 04, how can I get this data in excel??? Hope I am able to explain things...

Comment: If you go to export functions via Google Drive and export your spreadsheet to excel it works?

Comment: The page you speak about (Previous years) is empty. Please give another example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to POST the parameters to get the data of Dec 07 to Dec 04.

Here is the GAS code, then you need to do some work with the response content to adjust it to your needs.

```
function post() {
    var options = {
        "method" : "post",
        "payload": {
            "nav": "next",
            "type": "profit_cons",
            "sc_did": "RL",
            "start_year": 201212,
            "end_year": 200812,
            "max_year": 201212
        }
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/ranbaxylabs/consolidated-profit-loss/RL", options);

    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```